# Exception caught by widgets library Value not in range: 7

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to run flutter application in android studio, getting this error

```
Exception caught by widgets library Value not in range: 7
   The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      VendorTypeVerticalListItem file:///D:/downloads/31145802-fuodz-grocery-food-pharmacy-store- 
    parcelcourier-delivery-mobile-app-with-php-laravel-backend/1.3.3-fix-1/Apps/Customer/New%20Owners/lib/widgets/states/welcome.empty.dart:85:42
```

Iam Trying to run in android studio real device

welcome.empty.dart file line no 85 return VendorTypeVerticalListItem getting this error  Exception caught by widgets library Value not in range: 7

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/services/auth.service.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/utils/ui_spacer.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/view_models/welcome.vm.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/widgets/busy_indicator.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/widgets/custom_list_view.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/widgets/list_items/vendor_type.list_item.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/widgets/list_items/vendor_type.vertical_list_item.dart';
import 'package:masonry_grid/masonry_grid.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';
import 'package:fuodz/translations/welcome.i18n.dart';

class EmptyWelcome extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmptyWelcome({this.vm, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final WelcomeViewModel vm;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VStack(
      [
        VxBox(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: VStack(
              [
                ("Welcome".i18n +
                    (vm.isAuthenticated()
                        ? " ${AuthServices.currentUser?.name}"
                        : ""))
                    .text
                    .white
                    .xl3
                    .semiBold
                    .make(),
                "How can I help you today?".i18n.text.white.xl.medium.make(),
              ],
            ).py12(),
          ),
        ).color(AppColor.primaryColor).p20.make().wFull(context),
        //
        VStack(
          [
            HStack(
              [
                "I want to:".i18n.text.xl.medium.make().expand(),
                Icon(
                  vm.showGrid ? FlutterIcons.grid_fea : FlutterIcons.list_fea,
                ).p2().onInkTap(() {
                  vm.showGrid = !vm.showGrid;
                  vm.notifyListeners();
                }),
              ],
              crossAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            ).py4(),
            //list view
            !vm.showGrid
                ? CustomListView(
              noScrollPhysics: true,
              dataSet: vm.vendorTypes,
              isLoading: vm.isBusy,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final vendorType = vm.vendorTypes[index];
                return VendorTypeListItem(
                  vendorType,
                  onPressed: () {
                    vm.pageSelected(vendorType);
                  },
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => UiSpacer.emptySpace(),
            )
                : (vm.isBusy
                ? BusyIndicator().centered()
                : AnimationLimiter(
              child: MasonryGrid(
                column: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                children: List.generate(
                  vm.vendorTypes.length ?? 0,
                      (index) {
                    final vendorType = vm.vendorTypes[index];
                    return VendorTypeVerticalListItem(
                      vendorType,
                      onPressed: () {
                        vm.pageSelected(vendorType);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ))
                .py4(),
          ],
        ).p20(),
      ],
    ).scrollVertical();
  }
}
```

In this file, I am getting error, see the screenshot:

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: Please try to clarify your problem more precisely. Stack Overflow isn't a network with studies your code problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are trying to build the 7th widget in that column but the list you are using to build from does not have 7 items in it.
unfortunately, I can not say exactly what makes this error in your case.

ps: some might say it is not very wise to use a lot of packages in your code... it makes your app hard to trace and readable and you cannot easily understand what is going on.